# Can Django get know about client's location and language preferences?

Tags: python, django, localization

In my Django application I'd like to know client's language setting and change my project's localisation setting.

Comment: That's a great idea! You should definitely do that.

Comment: The client's language preferences are available in the HTTP `Accept-Language` header. See [Content Negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) and [RFC2616 section 14.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4).